# Where I can find the Python `pwd` module for MS Windows?

Tags: python, windows, passwd

I use the Python standard library `pwd` module on GNU+Linux, but now I try to run my application in Microsoft Windows and can not find it.

I'm using python 2.6.6. Where can I find the `pwd` module for use in Python on MS Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html#module-pwd):

> *Platforms:* Unix

You will need to go digging around in PyWin32 and MSDN for the Windows equivalents.